# Как сделать такой макет на flexbox? Раскладка на flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Как реализовать данный макет на flexbox? С CSS Grid это делается просто, но как на flexbox понять не могу. Проблема возникает при перестройке с планшетной версии на десктопную. Блоки сильно перестраиваются[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на чистом css никак - нужен js, чтобы на разрешении 750 убрать обертку над вторым и третьим блоком. jquery .unwrap() в помощь

Comment: Благодарю! Очень помогли